# Where scripts run in proxy mode?

Tags: proxy

Basically when we use browser to follow the proxy let's say x.x.x.x (Proxy server IP) my all internet traffic generated from the browser will be submitted to the proxy server and from there proxy server will act as a client and forward this request to the server showing that actual initiator of the request is proxy server itself.

***Question is: When we are using proxy server in browser for internet traffic, Where the scripts on that site will load ? on proxy server or on Web client ?***

According to me it loads on proxy server and the answer/requested resource will be responded to the actual client but still in doubt.

If possible need further clarification with example

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the client's perspective, nothing changes. Resources which were retrieved over the network are still retrieved over the network (only through a relay), and client-side scripts and actions remain client-side. (The script's output is not an HTTP "resource"; the script *itself* is.)

Comment: I have a scenaio which is confusing here..  When i use direct proxy which is on the WAN of my firewall my site is working with chrome and explorer, The same site is working with gateway (My firewall IP) in chrome but not in explorer. And on explorer showing me to enable the Javascript which is not the case in proxy mode.. What else could be the reason here ...As i was suspecting that there is no change in the firewall in both condition but the change is there in the browser....if you can assist will be helpful....

Comment: You'll have to investigate deeper than that. If you suspect there's a difference in network requests, then open up the browsers' "developer tools" and look at what requests are logged.